# Trying to detect and gather data on click outside application

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I would like to know if it is possible to, while running a WPF window application in Visual Studio, wait for the user to click anywhere on the screen (not necessarily inside the window of my application - for the purpose of my application, the click would most likely occur inside a browser page) and then gather the information about the click (like inside the window of which application the user clicked, or the selector of the html element the user clicked)? I know this question might be very confunsing but this is basically my last resort since researching on the Internet hasn't helped me much. Just to provide a better idea of what I seek, it's like what the 'Extract Structured Data' Activity does in UiPath. Oh and I'm using C# by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use this external library called [GlobalMouseHook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook).

> This library allows you to tap keyboard and mouse, detect and record their activity even when an application is inactive and runs in background.

**Here is what you can do with this library:**

- Mouse coordinates
- Mouse buttons clicked
- Mouse drag actions
- Mouse wheel scrolls
- Key presses and releases
- Special key states

Hope this helps.